# Chaining ajax request correctly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

hey people I'm facing an issue and I can't find a solution.
I'm trying to chain 2 rest call functions and after them use a function which uses the objects returned from both of them. For some reason something is not working I think its something to do with the syntax I wrote. I would like to understand why
 my code:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      var users = [];
      var user = null;

      function restCallA() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2",
          type: "GET",
          success: function(response) {
            users = response.data;
          }
        });
      }
      function restCallB() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "https://reqres.in/api/users/2",
          type: "GET",
          success: function(response) {
            user = response.data;
          }
        });
      }
      function myFun() {
        users.push(user);
        console.log(users);
      }
      restCallA()
        .then(restCallB())
        .then(myFun());
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

error:

> test.html:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `restCallA` and `restCallB` must return the result of each of their `$.ajax` calls, then you can chain them using `then()`.

Another issue is that you are invoking restCallB and myFun instead of passing the functions in as parameters:

```
restCallA()
        .then(restCallB())
        .then(myFun());
```

should be:

```
restCallA()
        .then(restCallB)
        .then(myFun);
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that's how it works. Where is the `promise` in `ajax`?

Comment: @denat how can I use the result of each ajax call if not inside the ajax call itself? I mean when i do restCallA(data).then(restCallB).then(myFun) I can't pass the data of the first function.... same for the second one

Comment: @hindi1991 both restCallB and myFun can accept a `data` parameter which will contain the result of the previous ajax request

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava you can manipulate the underlying Promise using `jqXHR.then(...)`. Source: [http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: @denat I understand but how tdo I write it down as a syntax? since I got no () on thr second function when I use .then chaining